# creating a text box field in Cakephp of array type

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

Can anyone help me that as i am new to CakePHP
i want to create a an input box of array type.

my code is

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('txt', array('type' => 'text','label' => 'Field 1')); ?>
```

output for this is :

```
<input type="text" id="AddmoreTxt" multiple="multiple" name="data[Addmore][txt]">
```

but i want the output like

```
<input type="text" id="AddmoreTxt" multiple="multiple" name="data[Addmore][txt][]">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally i find the answer. Let me know if it is not exactly correct thank you

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('txt', array('type' => 'text','label' => 'Field 1','name'=>'data[Addmore][txt][]')); ?>
```

Comment: this should work but I prefer the answer given by Sadikhasan. thanks

Answer (score 6):

Put `dot` after your fieldName like below mentioned in code. I have checked this code.

**CakePHP Code**

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('txt.', array('type' => 'text','label' => 'Field 1')); ?>
```

**Output**

```
<input type="text" id="AddmoreTxt" multiple="multiple" name="data[Addmore][txt][]">
```

Comment: Very satisfactory answer

Comment: @AlokKumarMishra Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will work better:

In your input, put **'.' (dot)** after field name.

`<?php echo $this->Form->input('txt.', array('type' => 'text','label' => 'Field 1'); ?>`